# Return percentile in pandas, taking availability into account

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a column in pandas with the following values:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, NaN]
```

And I want to determine what the 50%, 68% and 100% values are, but I want the 100% value to be NaN, since I have 10 values but only 9 values/numbers.

I've been trying with pd.quantiles, but that will return 4.0 for the 100% value.

Is there a better function/option to use, or will I have to create something a bit more custom here?

Thanks

Comment: what is the Statistical meaning of that?? How would you interpret that ?? percentile requires ordering of numbers, how can you say that NaN is higher than 4??

Comment: This doesnt make any sense based on the definition of a quantile. The 100% quantile would be the max value of the set. You would have to arbitrarily assign the NaN value to the max value in the set and I guess more importantly what is the point?